# How to calculate execution time

Tags: networking

I have to use mausezahn(mz tool) to send traffic and calculate the traffic rate .
I got an output for a particular case .

Mausezahn will send 100000 frames... 2.69 seconds (37175 packets per second)

I dont think this is the actual rate of traffic transfer because mz ran for a much longer time than the value stated above .

How can I calculate the time of execution of mz ?

Answer (score 0):

Like with every Linux command, you can display the execution time with `time`, e. g. `time mz`.